# Assistance needed with images ontop of tables

Tags: html, css

I'm currently creating an internal 4 page site. Each page has a table created with a map of a building as the background. On one page I have numerous dots placed on it. Each dot has its own style position for example: `<img src="dot.jpg" height="7" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 454px; top: 289px" width="7"/>`  and `<img src="dot.jpg" height="7" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 639px; top: 394px" width="7"/>`Is there a way I can move the table along with all of the dot.jpg's as 1 or will I need to move each one individually.  I'm fairly new to HTML. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    <table width="1280px" height="520px" border="1">
<tr>
<td background="XXXX-fullwcabinets.jpg" style="height: 516px">
<!-- ================================================= -->
<span title="ICQA
XXX9/1-19
">
<img src="dot.jpg" height="7" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 657px; top: 323px" width="7">
</span>
<!-- ================================================= -->
<span title="XXX13/1-38
XXX13/1-39
">
<img src="dot.jpg" height="7" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 657px; top: 288px" width="7">
</span>
<!-- ================================================= -->
<span title="XXX9/2-28
XXX9/2-29
XXX9/2-30
IDF9/2-31">
<img src="dot.jpg" height="7" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 620px; top: 288px" width="7">
</span>
<!-- ================================================= -->
```

Comment: For starters, include your code in the question. The relevant parts of it.

Comment: I did but I didn't see until now it cut out what i had put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local coordinate system for a containing element with `position: relative` will be the coordinate system for all things inside that have `position: absolute`.

Then, if you move the containing element, everything inside that will keep the relative position to the containing element.

Technically, an element with absolute positioning will look for the first parenting element that has absolute or relative or fixed (i.e. anything else than static) positioning and use that as its reference origin.

So, for example, run this snippet.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.first {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
.second {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly I would need to place the image in the container and have the dot.jpg correspond to the position inside the container instead of the position on the page. Currently the image is in a table and the dots are placed on top of that table.

Comment: Basically, yes. I'll make an example for you. Is there some reason why you have a table?

Comment: Now take a look at the example. I moved the container to the right with a simple margin and see how everything inside the container is still positioned relatively to the container, no matter where the container itself is.

Comment: the table was created because I did not know of another way to do what I wanted to at the time. It was also originally only going to be one page but i expanded it afterwords.

Comment: Thank you for your help, This will do what i need.